# Remote management using WMI XP PC's in a work group

Tags: wmi

Is it not possible to remotely manage XP sp2 PC from another XP sp3 computer using WMI where both of  PC are in a work group? I have run wmimgmt.msc right click WMI control the connect to another PC. I have also used WMI Tools which I downloaded. I have Administrative account on the remote computer. I tried everything I found on the net

including:

1. Remote enabled WMI on the remote computer
2. It must not be firewall issue as I tried everything including disabling it ( the firewall).
3. Gave my account  all permissions to the root and root\CIMV2 names paces on the remote computer
4. Created the same administrative account( Same user name and password) on local computer (not remote) as suggested by some people on the net.
5. and others

But I keep getting error like

1. Access denied
2. The RPC server is not available

I set up security event log on the remote computer and I got the clue that the account requesting is not my account . This way I guess that it not possible to manage my PC this way but I should set up my network so that both PC's are in the same domain. But I don't want this to happen now.

Is my guess right? If not what is wrong with me?. I am a newbie in this area.

Comment: any solution and sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everybody. I answer the question my self.
It is possible. The problem I was having was not creating the accounts correctly